# Add comma in a column with integers at a specified position (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
lat      | lon 
___________________
1234444  | 4302134123
134445445| 455463456
```

I want to separate with a comma the column lat after the third digit, while the column long after the second.

```
lat      | lon 
___________________
123,4444  | 43,02134123
134,445445| 45,5463456
```

What's the easist way to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can divide into two strings with `.str[i:j]` and add comma at the specified position:

```
df['lat'] = df['lat'].astype(str)
df['lon'] = df['lon'].astype(str)
df['lat'] = df['lat'].str[0:3] + ',' + df['lat'].str[3:]
df['lon'] = df['lon'].str[0:2] + ',' + df['lon'].str[2:]
df
Out[1]: 
          lat          lon
0    123,4444  43,02134123
1  134,445445   45,5463456
```